Reallocated sectors count keeps growing and hard drive occasionally creates grinding sound
I have a relatively new portable hard drive (only ~420 hours so far). But it already has some reallocated sectors issues and occasional creates scary grinding sound. I am not sure if this has anything to do with my moving large numbers of files from my two old hard drive to this portable hard drive.
The following screenshots shows the details: Just within one hour of use, I saw the reallocated sectors count grew from 5440 to 6032. I don't know how this is related to the 200 or 199 count in the menu below (appreciate it if anyone could explain their relations!). Is Current/Worst/Threshold 200/200/140 considered highly risky?
Is this an indicator that my portable hard drive is dying soon with substantial hardware failure?




I hope you know having thousands of reallocated sectors is a sign your HDD is failing. Transferring a large file absolutely didn’t cause the failure itself. So your device absolutely is failing. You should do research on how to read the threshold S.M.A.R.T data values. They differ from attribute to attribute.

If you pending reallocated sector attribute is anything but 0 it means you have failed sectors that had data on them that were moved to a sector that hadn’t failed.

This as a good answer which explains the attribute you are worried about. You have already exceeded the threshold value for that attribute from “good” to “caution” by a significant amount.

Its time to replace this disk. it can no longer be trusted, and if you continue to use it, you will eventually experience data loss. Make sure your backups are solid, and replace the drive. hopefully you will be able to return it for replacement since its not very old.

@Ramhound Thank you for your comments! Just curious, as a 1TB Disk has 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 sectors = 2147483648 sectors (mine is 4TB), why several thousands of reallocated sectors a concern?

@taylor - Because you described a situation where the attribute increased by a 1,000 in a very small timeframe. A healthy disk value is less than the threshold. Your reallocation event count is very close to the threshold also. I don’t understand the push back. You ask if your disk is failing, it is failing, your at the stage where no data loss has happened.

Your 4TB absolutely does not have 2147483648 spare sectors if that’s what you think that calculation is.
